# Apache2 Setting Up Multiple Domains

Tags: apache2, vps

So I've looked and google for a few hours on setting up multiple domains, and I'm about to give up.

Here's my latest attempt:

ports.conf:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

# NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

sites-available/data.paulbgd.me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  www.data.paulbgd.me
        ServerAlias data.paulbgd.me

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/data.paulbgd.me/

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/data.paulbgd.me/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>


        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/data.paulbgd.me/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/data.paulbgd.me/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

No errors on apache restart. The domain's dns has it's a record set to my VPS's ip.

EDIT: Forgot to mention something. When I go to the domain I don't get a "can't connect" page, I just get a blank page. And on that note:

/var/www/data.paulbgd.me/index.php:

```
<h2>Works!</h2>
```

Comment: You wrote `DirectoryIndex index.html` but `/var/www/data.paulbgd.me/index.php` has another extension you should use the same file extension. Try to change it and show us your log records.

Comment: You have commented out NameVirtualHost *:80 in ports.conf. Why? Also you define index.html as Directory Index, but have a index.php. If the php file is not working when you directly call it, make shure you have php installed.

Comment: Alright, I'll check these suggestions out.

Comment: Hmph, I had an error when I restarted (I changed both of these things). http://l.paulbgd.me/IyhgHv

Comment: What version of ubuntu do you use? And have you enabled the vhost with: sudo a2ensite data.paulbgd.me ? (Sorry the NameVirtualHost was wrong. You can comment it out)